# Multiple Login roles required in my app - how to

Tags: android, sqlite, server

I have created a Loan Application for an NGO in android in which organization employee login is required and created a Login table in SQLite database for that and that work is done and

Now there are different roles for Loan officer(employee) and Branch Manager . As per now employee can login but Branch Manager information (password , username) is not stored in SQLite database but on server .

Now Loan Officer do not have some roles that Branch manager has and , **now my client wants when Loan Officer logged out Branch Manager can Log in** and acces his roles .

Is that Possible ? 
What should i do ? 
Am I supposed get all information from Branch Manager Login table from server and store inside another table in SQlite .

Please help ?

Comment: I will provide more information , if anybody have Question regarding . .

Comment: so you looking for store Branch manager details on Sqlite ?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Just set a user table which also includes the allowed permission level for that user. When the user logs in, the app knows the permission level (i.e.: 0 is admin, 1 is power user, 2 is normal user, 3 is casual user, ...). Depending on that level, the app manages the visibility of certain information and sets the UI accordingly.

Comment: @Fantômas Okay so you are Saying i need to create another table login table for Branch Manager in SQlite database ? 
Actually my Android App is linked with Web App in Which Client add User's in Tablet and send that data to Server . and Branch Manager is also employee but credentials are stored in Web App on server . 
How can i get that credentials for Branch Manager ?

Comment: @Ashish yes and Branch Manager info is already stored on server but not in SQLite .

Comment: @Fantômas that is exactly what i am talking about but the problem is , Do Branch Manager needs to create an account first ? but my client doesn't want that because he already created account through web App and credentials are stored on server so Client wants get credentials from server . 
How can i do that ? share some code?

Comment: No. I mean that the existing user table should have a field where to store the privilege level. If the credential come from a remote database, you should use the appropriate methods to get that information.

Comment: @Fantômas yes actually i am getting all the user's login info from remote database and some columns were missing means not storing in table , but okay now i know . Thanks